# Conflict: Single website but different connection strings. ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a web application, which will be used by multiple users at different locations,
I have a a page where they will be able to select the server and database to begin with.
All server and database structure is same, so no problem with that.

Now I need a way where I can save connection strings somewhere for each client.
As you know modifying web.config > connection string will affect others accessing it, and cant use a class(get set).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the selection connection **key** (remember that all the connection strings are in the `web.config` file) into a cookie so each client could reuse the last selected one.

Comment: Thanks Dare Devil 73.